# Персонаж в Unity проваливается сквозь карту

Tags: unity3d

При замене капсуля на готового персонажа в obj и добавлении ему Rigidbody, он начинает проваливаться сквозь карту. Тег Ground на поверхности включен.
С капсулем всё работает, с персонажем - нет.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Скорость перемещения персонажа")]
    public float speed = 7f;

    [Header("Сила прыжка")]
    public float jumpPower = 200f;

    [Header("Мы на земле?")]
    public bool ground;

    public Rigidbody rb;

    private void Update()
    {
        GetInput();
    }

    private void GetInput()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            transform.localPosition += transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            transform.localPosition += -transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            transform.localPosition += -transform.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            transform.localPosition += transform.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            if (ground == true)
            {
                rb.AddForce(transform.up * jumpPower);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
        {
            ground = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
        {
            ground = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А коллайдер есть на персонаже? И вообще, просто возьмите и аккуратно сравните набор компонентов и их свойства для эти двух объектов, явно есть отличия.

Comment: А точняк! Спасибо, добрый человек!

Comment: Персонажа нужно двигать, а не телепортировать, вот и проваливается.